# Directive ng-disabled not working in ionic

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

The following code doesn't disable the radio button when i run the ionic application.even ng-hide doesnt work.`<input type="radio" ng-disabled="true">`

Comment: Could you include the code in your actual post?

Comment: <input type="radio" ng-disabled="true">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked by connecting a variable to the input like below

```
<input type="radio" [disabled]="diablebtn">
```